# Core Data delete objects .allObjects.count not updating

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have to objects on my core data model. Pin and PhotoFrame

Pin has a relationship with PhotoFrame.

I have successfully add images to Pin and successfully delete them from the context and the storeCordinator. My issue is that when ever I delete the Image(objects) that are linked with Pin, I can verify that are deleted by making a fetch again or checking in my DB that are deleted BUT if I write

```
pin.images.allObjects.count
```

I get the number of images that the object had before the deletion and after.

Here is my code

```
var results = [PhotoFrame]()
        do{
            results = try stack!.context.fetch(frc.fetchRequest) as! [PhotoFrame]
        }catch{
            print("INTERNAL ERROR : Fetch")
        }

        for result in results{
            stack!.context.delete(result)
            print("deleted")
        }

        //pin!.numberOfImages = 0
        loadMorePictures.isEnabled = false
        do{
            try stack!.context.save()
        }catch{
            print("Error Saving LoadMorePictures Action Internal Error")
        }

        do{
            results = try stack!.context.fetch(frc.fetchRequest) as! [PhotoFrame]
        }catch{
            print("INTERNAL ERROR : : Fetch")
        }

        print(results.count) // <--- 0

        print("pin.images?.allObjects.count : \(pin!.images?.allObjects.count)") <-- 21
```

The second time I am fetching ,results = 0 
and pin.images.allObjects.count = 21

Shouldn't that get update automatically?

Thanks a lot I am new on Core Data

Comment: That depends. What is `allObjects`? It's not part of Core Data.

Comment: Have you defined an inverse relationship from PhotoFrame to Pin?  If so, what delete rule have you specified for it?

Comment: @TomHarrington  var allObjects: [Any] { get }
Description 
An array containing the set’s members, or an empty array if the set has no members. Since this get's update when it appends new objects I "assume" that when the objects are removed then the array should be empty

Comment: @pbasdf :FROM PhotoFrame to Pin : Relationship : pin | Destination : Pin | Inverse : images | Delete Rule : Nullify.

    FROM Pin to PhotoFrame : OPTIONAL | Relationship : images | Destination : PhotoFrame | Inverse : pin | Delete Rule : Cascade

Would it help more if I post 2 screenshots of my Model?

By the way the only way to get the number of objects is by fetching and getting the count of the [results]?